# 'pic_name' field doesn't have a default value Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

so im trying to insert the name of picture into Mysql DB but after i submit the form it gives me a error of 'pic_name' field doesn't have a default value... that means my controller is not storing value of form

here is my blade :

```
<div>
    <form action="/product_store" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <input type="text" name="name_product">
        <input type="file" name="file_product">
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

and controller:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $original_name= $request->file('file_product')->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = $request->file('file_product')->store('storage');
        Product::create(['name' => $request['name_product'], 'pic_name' => $original_name]);
    }
```

**name field is storing perfectly** so there is no problem with my web.php

Comment: i did it just give me the original name of file there is no problem with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `pic_name` fillable in model.

```
class Product extends Model
{

     protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'pic_name'
    ];

}
```

**Note :** sometimes what happened in your table that feild value is not set for default or not null. so while inserting data you don't get that value to insert in that case you need to make as default null.

```
Table-> feild -> make it null
```

-> make null if you don't want to store value while insert